# Get eigenvalues for large dense matrix inR

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix (36169*36169), formal class 'dgCMatrix' R package "Matrix".

I need the sum of eigenvalues, so I need to either calculate eigenvalues or the trace of this matrix.

I have tried to convert the matrix to 'normal' matrix format using as.matrix(), to be able to use matrix.trace(). Here I have memory problems, when trying to convert the file  I get error message: Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c,

Next step I search for ways to get the diagonal values (trace) directly for the dgcMatrix, now I found that I could use

Diag signature(x = "dgCMatrix") in the Matrix package, together with setMethod, but I haven't been able to find a example on how to use it.

Does any one here have an example code showing how this work or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(Matrix)

set.seed(123)
M <- as(matrix(rnorm(4), 2), "dgCMatrix") # test data

sum(diag(M))
[1] -0.4899673
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is `sum(diag(M))`:

```
set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(rnorm(10000), 100, 100)

E <- eigen(M)
sum(Re(E$values)); sum(diag(M)) # equal
```